# OPU UA Server Questions

Tags: opc

I have been looking at the OPC UA Specification parts, however they do not give you a list of classes and function and tell you how they work. Is there something like that?

Also the server, the 1st thing it does is creates an Object right? 
one of Server ? 
what are the steps from the Server point of view ?

Answer (score 1):

You should *strongly* consider using one of the available SDKs if you're looking to build an OPC-UA server.

That being said, UA Part 6 describes the encoding of the built-in datatypes. A schema describing many of the other structured types is available here: http://opcfoundation.org/UA/schemas/1.02/Opc.Ua.Types.xsd, along with some other useful XML files.

Answer (score 1):

As you can read into the Part 1 : Overview and Concepts of the OPC UA Specification :

> OPC  UA  defines  a  common  infrastructure  model  to  facilitate 
>   this  information  exchange  OPC UA specifies the following:
>
> - The information model to represent structure, behaviour and semantics.
> - The message model to interact between applications.
> - The communication model to transfer the data between end-points.
> - The conformance model to guarantee interoperability between systems.

You could get the OPC UA Stack from the OPC Foundation if you are member of it, but this is only the communication part of a Server/Client application.
Then you have to implement your own Server/Client (AddressSpace manager, Session Manager, Subscription Manager, Certificate manager,...) or buy a SDK that already contains all the required features of an OPC UA Server or Client and will allow you to launch a Server/Client with few code lines.